# Is there a Magento 2 Check-out specifically designed for gift deliveries/shipments?

Tags: checkout, onestepcheckout

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
Extensions from Amasty
```

Imagine an **on-line flower store** or a gift basket shop. **A customer will come on there to actually send a present to someone else** (meaning their Billing and Delivery information will always be *different*). It occurred to me that our use case is different than the majority of Magento websites/stores because in the majority of cases a customer will come onto your website to buy a book, piece of clothing, program etc. which they will be buying for themselves (both their Delivery and Billing address will be the same).

We started using Amasty's One Step Checkout but many of our customers are confused and fill in the Delivery and Billing info incorrectly = either both will be the same which misses the name and address of the person the flowers are to be delivered to or they swap it opposite (put their details into Delivery info and the person who is receiving the gift into Billing). This is such a big problem that we asked Amasty to move the Email (login) address up above where it shows the Delivery Info but it did not seem to help.

**How to resolve this? (make it truly fool-proof)** *Are there any Check-outs or modifications designed specifically for this use case? (I must not be the only merchant in the predicament).*

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you need a Gift Registry module to be able to meet this requirement. You can refer to this module: https://store.magenest.com/magento-2/gift-registry.html. Hope it helps you.